# What's a good way to access the bugzilla webservice from a different domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, perl, bugzilla

I have two sites `products.company.com` and `bugzilla.internal.com`. I would like to access bug information from the products.company.com page. I set up a jQuery ajax function to make a jsonrpc call to `bugzilla.internal.com/jsonrpc.cgi`. However due to cross domain scripting restrictions, this was blocked by apache (as expected). So then I shot the ajax to a cgi script on products.company.com and then used curl in that script to shoot off the request to `bugzilla.internal.com/jsonrpc.cgi`, but now it says

> You don't have permission to access
>   /jsonrpc.cgi

What to do?

if it makes the task any simpler, I only want to use the [get bug](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#get) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web server at products.company.com is Apache, you can set up a ProxyPass.

If you can't modify web server configuration, then a simple proxy cgi at products.company.com can do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;
use CGI qw(:standard);



my $URL='http://bugzilla.internal.com/jsonrpc.cgi';

my $q = new CGI;
my $query = &query_string();

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $URL);
$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->content($query);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_success) {
   printf "Content-Type: %s\n\n", $res->header('Content-Type');
   print $res->content;
} else {
   printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
   print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
}



print $cgi->header(-type => 'text/xml');
print $response->decoded_content;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. You can have `products.company.com` make the request to `bugzilla.internal.com` and have it basically act as a proxy.

Another option would be to use jsonp from the client - this will allow for cross domain calls. [Here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) a pretty good IBM article on getting started with jsonp.

Comment: Doesn't jsonp only allow me to EXTRACT json data from another server? In my situation I want to SEND json data to the bugzilla webservice.

Answer (score 0):

There are several work arounds for cross domain scripting restrictions. I haven't tested it, but [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM) seems to do what you want.